# What is the socket path for a custom FCGI Application spawned by the local http server? (ie apache/mod_fcgid, lighttpd/mod_fastcgi, etc. )

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fastcgi, mod-fcgid, unix-socket

I'm working on a fastcgi dev kit written in objective-c/cocoa, that mimics the behavior and structure of AppKit/UIKit (app deleagates, runloops, event queues etc). I've done my homework on fastcgi, libfcgi, the fastcgi objective c implementations using libfcgi and I've come to the sad realization that, in order to make it 100% "Cocoa" I'd have to implement the protocol myself, from scratch (the way libfcgi is designed to "loop" doesn't jive well with CoreFoundation RunLoops and event queues).

That being said, there are the following cases for a fastcgi-responder application as per the documentation (FCGI Whitepaper) at fastcgi.com:

1. The application is local to the web server and is spawned by the latter as needed to fulfill incoming requests
2. The application is local or remote to the web server, but the web server assumes it is already running and communicates with it via domain socket or tcp/ip socket.

I'm fine with the second case because I have control over the socket path/the ip address and port where I want my app to listen: I know where my channel of communication is.

The problem I hve is with the first scenario. I have been sifting throuh `fci_stdio.c` and `fcgiapp.c` looking at `FCGX_Accept_r`, `FCGX_InitRequest`, `FCGX_Stream` and the like and I can't seem to find what socket it tries to read from.

No, it's not `stdin` as this gets hijacked and "enveloped" into a `FCGI_FILE` struct in `fcgi_stdio.h` as specified in the documentation at fastcgi.com. I admit my posix programming days are far behind me and I am a bit rusty. I'm definetly missing something.

I've tried listening to `stdin` in my app and it comes up with posix error 57 (Unspecified error) and no data. Here's a sample of the output I get in the log on  a sample application:

```
2013-05-01 11:40:01.486 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] /Users/catalin/Sites/fcgi/Test-FCGIKit-CocoaBundle.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Test-FCGIKit
2013-05-01 11:40:01.495 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] applicationWillFinishLaunching:
2013-05-01 11:40:01.497 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] startRunLoop
2013-05-01 11:40:01.498 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] applicationDidFinishLaunching:
2013-05-01 11:40:01.500 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] * Waiting for events 
2013-05-01 11:40:01.501 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] didReadToEndOfStdIn:
2013-05-01 11:40:01.502 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] NSConcreteNotification 0x7fb3d9806670 {name = NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification; object = <NSConcreteFileHandle: 0x7fb3d8c15030>; userInfo = {
    NSFileHandleError = 57;
    NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem = <>;
}}
2013-05-01 11:40:01.504 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] * Waiting for events 
2013-05-01 11:40:01.508 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] * Processed event 
2013-05-01 11:40:01.510 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] * Waiting for events 
[Wed May 01 11:40:41 2013] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
[Wed May 01 11:40:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: Test-FCGIKit
2013-05-01 11:40:43.337 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] Caught SIGTERM. Terminating.
2013-05-01 11:40:43.338 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] terminate:
2013-05-01 11:40:43.339 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] applicationShouldTerminate:
2013-05-01 11:40:43.343 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] quit
2013-05-01 11:40:43.345 Test-FCGIKit[2477:707] applicationWillTerminate:
```

- Please don't be mislead by the message names: they're meant to be exactly the same as AppKit/UIKit but they are not from `NSApplication`.
  ** It's fine for it to timeout as I not doing anything in the code to respond to the request or to send any data whatsoever back to the server (I'm pretty faraway from that).

How does the app know what socket path to listen to (read from/write to) if the server creates the socket dynamically upon request?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, after a bit more digging, trial and error, a lot of coffe and some fresh air I came acress a paragraph in the FastCGI specification at http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html

> **2.2 File Descriptors**
>
> The Web server leaves a single file descriptor, FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO, open when the application begins execution. This descriptor refers to a listening socket created by the Web server.
>
> FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO equals STDIN_FILENO. The standard descriptors STDOUT_FILENO and STDERR_FILENO are closed when the application begins execution. A reliable method for an application to determine whether it was invoked using CGI or FastCGI is to call getpeername(FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO), which returns -1 with errno set to ENOTCONN for a FastCGI application.
>
> The Web server's choice of reliable transport, Unix stream pipes (AF_UNIX) or TCP/IP (AF_INET), is implicit in the internal state of the FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO socket.

So, therefore, I should really not care about the actual physical path of the socket, since it's being passed to my app via the `STDIN` stream. All I need to do is listen. Don't we all ?!

Since I know what to listen for, I can use `[NSFileHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify]` (see Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify)) to listen to the socket and respond to requests.

Whew!